# Fiddler for website running on remote machine

Tags: fiddler

I need to monitor a http request and response for web site running on remote web server. The web server makes lot of web service call and would like to trace them.

If the web site was running locally, Fiddler traces every web service call request and provides me with a report. Could someone please help me with how the same is possible

*e.g.

*If the web application is running locally and  calls two web services fiddler shows the total time on statistics. However, if the web application is running on web server hosted on different web server hosted internally (intranet) and I ran fiddler on my machine,  I don't get the statistics for each web service call. All I can see is the total time for the aspx page.**

So question is how (if possible) can I trace the statistics of each web services invoked by web application that's running on different machine and fiddler is running on my machine.

Thanks.

Comment: What OS is your server running?

Comment: You need to explain what access to the server you **do** have. If you can run whatever you want on the server, simply running Fiddler in -quiet mode inside a service account on the server.

Comment: Thanks @EricLaw, please see my updated question above. I'm trying to run fiddler on my local machine and trace the web application running on different web server.

Answer (score 4):

You could always use WireShark http://www.wireshark.org/ to catch all the packets, if you are on the same network as the server, that is.

Comment: Only if the network is configured in a really crappy way. Otherwise you don't get packets which are not for you unless they are broadcasts.

Comment: The primary reason for me trying to use fiddler in this manner is to trace and see how long each web service calls takes. Is this possible with Wireshark? From what I read, wireshark is more for network trouble shooting rather than tracing performance of web site?

Comment: Indeed you can see the total time each call takes, it is just quite more a hassle to filter out all the traffic (And considering what @ThiefMaster said, it only works if the network is configured in a bad way). But that was how I could find all IM-traffic in my school, because of lousy configuration. The thing with wireshark is that you can read all the packages that comes, and get a summary of the packages (and their total time of transmission)

Answer (score 3):

Say you're running a website on port 80 of a machine named WEBSERVER.  You're connecting to the website using Internet Explorer Mobile Edition on a Windows SmartPhone device for which you cannot configure the web proxy.  You want to capture the traffic from the phone and the server's response.

> 0.)Start Fiddler on the WEBSERVER machine, running on the default port of 8888.

```
1.)Click Tools | Fiddler Options, and ensure the "Allow remote clients to connect" checkbox is checked.  Restart if needed.
2.)Choose Rules | Customize Rules.
3.)Inside the OnBeforeRequest handler, add a new line of code:
if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "webserver:8888") oSession.host = "webserver:80";
5.)  navigate to http://webserver:8888
```

Requests from the SmartPhone will appear in Fiddler.  The requests are forwarded from port 8888 to port 80 where the webserver is running.  The responses are sent back through Fiddler to the SmartPhone, which has no idea that the content originally came from port 80.

Comment: Question: Can I use Fiddler as a reverse proxy without changing the port that the client application targets?
A:Yes, although you must reconfigure both your web server software and Fiddler.  First, you must reconfigure your web server to listen on a different port.  For instance, if your web server runs on port 80, you must reconfigure it to run on port 81.  Then, you must reconfigure Fiddler to listen on port 80.  Then, you must select either of the two options described above so Fiddler properly forwards the traffic to the web server which is now running on a different port.

Comment: Fiddler can operate as a "reverse proxy" which means that it can run on the server and forward inbound requests to a different port or web server.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup Fiddler in your machine and set it as a proxy in the web application you want trace. Easy inside a network, not so easy accross the interwebs.